# font-size/font-family has no effect

Tags: xsl-fo, font-size, font-family

This is a related issue to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883068/how-to-select-ancestor-based-on-ancestors-attribute).

I have modified the code suggested for preface headings to modify the p tags underneath the headings.

```
<xsl:template match="topic[title='Preface']/body/section/p">
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="preface.p">
            <xsl:apply-imports/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

---

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="preface.p">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Helvetica</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">8pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
```

The color changes the desired text - and only the desired text, so I know it is grabbing the correct nodes. However, the font family and size have no effect.

Does anyone know of anything I can check that might be over-riding the code?

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't have the attributes `font-family` or `font-size`, they are CSS properties, try this:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="preface.p">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">font-family: Helvetica; color: red; font-size: 8pt;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Comment: the template match code resides in my dita2fo shell file and the attribute-set is in a dita2fo-parms file. This is all XSL FO at this point - correct?

If I were to run the "name='style'" attribute as you suggest I would receive:  Invalid property name 'style'. Property ignored.

Comment: Ah, I don't know XSL FO, I assumed you used the code to generate HTML.